# Local Max of an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble with the following problem.

> $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{t^2-4}{1+cos^2(t)}dt$
>
> At what value of $x$ does the local max of $f(x)$ occur?

I've tried just taking the integral then finding the Max using critical points, but I can't find a way to make the integration straight forward using trig identities and algebra. So either I'm missing something on that front or there is another approach I'm not privy to.

Comment: Consider the points $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient that $f'(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{1+(\cos x)^2}=0$ then $x=\pm 2$ as a result $x=-2$ is local max of $f$.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed to see. I'd read through the Second Fundamental Theorem, but hadn't yet internalized it. Or rather, I'd read through the steps that lead from,

$f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \,dt$

to

$f'(x)=g(t)$

but had never seen it expressed so plainly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is a theorem about differentiating functions of the form
$$
f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \,dt
$$
It's a very important theorem.  Some may even call it fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Check out variations of Leibniz's rules and you will find that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int\limits_{u\left(x\right)}^{v\left(x\right)} f\left(x\right)\:dx & = \int\limits_{u\left(x\right)}^{v\left(x\right)}\frac{\partial f\left(x\right)}{\partial x}dx=f\left(v\left(x\right)\right)v'\left(x\right)-f\left(u\left(x\right)\right)u'\left(x\right).\tag{1}
\end{align}
This is merely an extension of the fundamental theorem of calculus/integration, which also says that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int\limits_0^x f\left(t\right)\:dt & =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F\left(x\right)-F\left(0\right)\right]=f\left(x\right).\tag{2}
\end{align}
Therefore, the $t$ is merely a dummy variable of integration which is swapped out during the integration, leaving us with a function of $x$, leaving us with, applied to your problem,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^x f\left(t\right)\:dx\bigg|_{f\left(t\right)=\frac{t^2-4}{1+\cos\left(t\right)}}=\frac{x^2-4}{1+\cos^2\left(x\right)},\tag{3}
\end{align}
and now we may apply the first derivative to this function of $x$ to find local extremum.

Please note that in (1),(2) and (3), it is also fine to use an ordinary differential operator and I have used the partial to get the point across.